# Material affecting all prefabs?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, shader, sprite

I am working on 2D platform game. I have a sprite with a material and a shader I found [here](http://www.shaderslab.com/index.php?post/Dissolve-sprite).

The shader have a value property that effect the dissolve effect of the sprite,
but if I have the same GameObject multi times in my scene (as a prefab or instantiated through code), changing the dissolve value on one material affects all GameObjects with the same material (I tried changing material name, clone the material and all kind of stuff), I think I understated now that it his happening because I use the same sprite (image)

What can I do to avoid that kind of behavior?

```
float dissolvePower = dissoleMaterial.GetFloat(dissolveProperty);        
float minus = -0.1f;
while (dissolvePower > 0)
{
    //print(dissolvePower);
    dissolvePower += minus;           
    dissoleMaterial.SetFloat(dissolveProperty, dissolvePower);           
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.07f);
}
print("Exit DeathDissolve()");
Destroy(gameObject);
```

Comment: Post the code you use to change the material or color

Comment: You should edit your answer with the code as it is not particulary readable in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the *same* material for each of your GameObjects.

Therefore, if you change a property (like the dissolve value) of the material, whether you do this in the Inspector for the GameObject or on the material itself, you will change the value for each GameObject that uses that material.

To avoid this, you need another material. You could duplicate the material, call it something different, and apply that material to a GameObject you want to be different.

Comment: thanks for your answer... yes i know, i am changing the matrerial for each game object, and other game object are not effected by the change, only the one with same sprites!

Comment: Material materialClone = Instantiate<Material>(materialDissolve);